# PHP and web API

Tags: php, api

I am having some issues writing a block of PHP that will allow me to access a web api with credentials.  Edit: Current non-functioning code block with proposed changes:

```
<?php 

$agent = array('ID' => '', 'Label' => '');

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'APIurlHere');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'ID:pass');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $agent);
curl_setopt($curl, CUROPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$agent = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);


var_dump($agent);
```

I'm honestly at a real loss here, I wouldn't call myself a web developer, but I have had some experience with HTML/asp.net/C#/google polymer, but both web APIs and PHP are new to me.

What I am looking to do is retrieve an agent object from the URL request (which I believe comes back in XML format?) and store that data in a php variable.

Some of the issues I have run into is "error 411" which is asking me to limit the response (although somehow I am not getting that error any more after I added the postfields line, not sure how) and being unable to actually view the xml/agent object I should be getting back.

**Updated code:**

```
<?php 


$agent = array('ID' => '', 'Label' => '');

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'URL');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'ID:pass');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $agent);
curl_setopt($curl, CUROPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


$agent = curl_exec($curl);
$agent = json_decode($agent, true);
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($agent);
print $agent;
```

The object I am trying to receive is not in XML like I originally thought, but is in json.  When I try to view what is in the parsed json var 'agent' all I see is the int value 1.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option to get the response from the call.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$xml = curl_exec($curl);
```

Now you can parse the XML in `$xml`.

This won't work:

```
echo $agent;
```

You can't echo an array, you can only echo numbers and strings. If you want to see what's in an array, use

```
var_dump($agent);
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to be storing anything in the $xml object.  are my curl_setopt statements correct? I don't believe I fully understand what the curlopt_postfields statement does

Comment: Have you put the proper parameters in the `$agent` array?

Comment: No I haven't I will test that out and get back to you.  Currently when I echo $xml I get a displayed value "1"

Comment: Ok so after reinspecting the API documentation, I don't believe it actually returns in xml format, but just returns the agent object,

So, I have $agent = curl_exec($curl);
and var_dump($agent)
However the var_dump displays "bool(true)".  I am not sure what that means in the slightest.

Btw I really appreciate your help

Comment: Are you sure you added `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`? `curl_exec()` returns `true` if it's successful and you haven't used that option. Otherwise it returns the response as a string.

Comment: It's not possible to return an object through `curl`, you can only return a string of bytes. If it's not returning XML it probably returns JSON. Once you fix your code to capture the return data, you use `json_decode()` to decode it.

Comment: Yeah you are correct, I went back again through the api documentation, it returns json.  Also I do have the curopt_returntransfer and the curl_exec() used.

When I do the var_dump on my decoded json variable, I get a int(1) response.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. Edit your question and add the updated code at the end (don't remove the original code).

Comment: Just updated. I am sure I am doing something wrong, just haven't found what it is yet.

Comment: Typo: `CUROPT` instead of `CURLOPT`. You should have gotten a warning about that. Make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` enabled while debugging.

Comment: I'll edit this in the main question, but the development platform I am working is wordpress using the PHP Code Widget. So I am working very blind when it comes to syntax and errors.